# How to use reaction as button in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

If we have a message with ⬇️ and ⬆️ Reaction.
How can we get all users reacted in particular emojis and how to use as button.

Like,
If a user reacts his name will be added in message along with the emoji which he reached.

Comment: check [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)

Comment: Can someone reply by code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example this is not the best method since this will be active on all bot messages when someone reacts with ⬆️. The best is save the message id that you want then do a check here to make sure it is the wanted message.

If `message.id` is not an option then make a dedicated channel for this and hard code the id of that channel, this is not the best practice but it will work.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = channel.get_message(payload.message_id)
    # guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name


    # skip DM messages
    if isinstance(channel, discord.DMChannel):
        return


    # only work if in bot is the author
    # skip messages not by bot
    # skip reactions by the bot
    if message.author.id != bot.user.id or payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
        return

    if emoji == '⬆️':
        up_users = f"{message.content} \n {user.name}"
        await message.edit(up_users)


    # remove user reaction 
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
    await reaction.remove(payload.member)
```

Comment: You can replace `get` to `fetch` if the `channel` is Nonetype object.